# Concourse add file to docker image just once

Tags: docker, concourse

I am using concourse for our build system.

Concourse caches docker images so that we don't need to go through the download process each on subsequent runs.

I want to add a binary file to the docker image which I will pull from the internet, but I only want to do it the first time the docker image is pulled and created by concourse.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: [Build your own image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/) and [push it to a repo](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_six/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the [docker-image-resource](https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource). You can define a Dockerfile with all of the dependencies that you want, and then push that as a resource that can be used in later builds. We wrote a [tutorial](http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/concourse-docker-image-resource-cache-tutorial/) on this that might clear things up a bit.